# How to auto sync with server when network came in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have some data in DB during offline mode. I want to sync with server when device once comes to online. I am trying with `Reachability`. But i am not getting any response from `Reachability`. I am trying below code, but its not working.

I call this method in `ViewDidiLoad` :

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
```

Then call this method :

```
-(BOOL)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification*)note
{
  BOOL status =YES;

  Reachability * reach = [note object];
  if ([reach currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable )
  {
    status = NO;
    NSLog(@"NetWork is not Available");
  }
  else
  {
    status = YES;
    NSLog(@"NetWork is Available");
  }
  return status;
```

}

But nothing is happening. Please anybody suggest me. My requirement is when networks is come that time automatically db data will sync with server. No need to touch the device.

Thanks in advanced...

Comment: have you initialise and startNotifier in application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ??

Comment: try with this instance method [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used the reachability class for network check like 
In ViewDidload method add below line :

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
             addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:)
             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
             object:nil];
```

kReachabilityChangedNotification is set in Reachability class.

Also add the below method :

```
-(void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes

    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");

            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have used above code for network check.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing to start the notifier.

Make a reachability object/property say "internetReachability" and when u add the observer, start the notifier.

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
    internetReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [internetReachability startNotifier];

Hope this helps.:)

Comment: Where are u adding the method that adds the observer? Make the call in  "- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions" method in AppDelegate.m. It should work. I have used the same for wifiReachability and it works.

Comment: BUt i need every time in app . Every time it will check network and if available it'll sync

Comment: Yes. Thats why u have to put it in applicationDidFinishLaunching method coz that gets called everytime u launch ur app and an observer is added when u start ur app. Try it. It should work.

Comment: not during launch app. In app also, suppose i save some data in DB during offline and suddenly network come that time also it will be sync with server. Not only during launch time. It should be in app also.

Comment: If u add it in applicationDidFinishLaunching, the observer will be set. So everytime ur network changes(network becomes available/unavailable) ur reachabilityChanged method will b called. It will work everytime. And u can check for ur database objects count when network is available if there are objects, then sync  else do nothing.